# Tweet to twitter or post to facebook by user's credentials in the PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

I have a form with 2 fields (username, password) and a select box (Facebook or Twitter). 
I have also registered applications with Facebook and Twitter. Is there some way to post to a user's wall in Facebook or to tweet to a user's Twitter account?

I have found some libraries for PHP such as Facebook-SDK and TwitterOAuth, but I can't find this functionality in them. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to post to twitter by using only username and password. Without the need for user to connect to your twitter application. I've done this using [twitter's XAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) authentication. I'm not sure about facebook. Never build an app for it.

However, since you use web application, it's recommended that you use OAuth. I've used [Abraham's OAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) before. [The exact API function you needed is](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/index.php):

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "this status sent from twitter OAUTH API"));
```

Try download the whole project and and upload it to your server, and run it. Don't forget to set **CONSUMER_KEY** and **CONSUMER_SECRET** of your application.

Comment: can you give me an example of using xAuth, because i can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this library to construct a tweet application.
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

I've also used this library with CodeIgniter http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For reference sake:  [use this library php-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/) as its the simplest I have used and it just works.